# NoReverseMatch at /blog/

Tags: django, django-urls

estoy intentando mostrar en mi archivo blog.html los post asociados a una categoria de la siguiente manera:

```
 {% for i in posts %}
        {% for j in i.categoria.all %}
            <a href="{% url 'categoria' categoria.id %}">{{j.nombre}}</a>
            | &nbsp;
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

pero me muestra error de ReverseMatch y en la página del error de Django me muestra unun error:

**Reverse for 'categoria' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/categoria/(?P<categoria_id>[^/]+)/$']**

Y me manda a está linea de codigo en un archivo html de base, el cual es heredado por blog.html

```
    <li class="nav-item {% if request.path == '/servicios/' %}active{% endif %} px-lg-4"> 
<a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-expanded" href="{% url 'servicios' %}">Servicios</a></li>
```

Asi tengo el url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.blog, name='blog'),
    path('categoria/<categoria_id>/', views.categoria, name='categoria'), # < Nombre del parametro que le vamos a enviar por la urls >
]
```

Y asi tengo la vista:

```
def categoria(request, categoria_id):   # El segundo parametro se enviar por la urls de site de forma manual

    categoria = Categoria.objects.get(id = categoria_id)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(categoria = categoria)  # Filtar por categoria y agregamos
    return render(request, "templates/categorias.html", {'categoria':categoria, 'posts': posts})
```

Se que está un poco largo pero ojala puedan ayudarme <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desglosando lo que te pone aqui:

```
Reverse for 'categoria' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/categoria/(?P<categoria_id>[^/]+)/$']
```

Te dice que esta intento buscar un match para la url 'de nombre categoria' con los argumentos ('',), esto significa que no esta pasando el parametro categoria_id, por eso se muestra asi ('',)

Entonces lo mas probable es que el error se encuentre aquí:

```
{% for i in posts %}
        {% for j in i.categoria.all %}
            <a href="{% url 'categoria' categoria.id %}">{{j.nombre}}</a>
            | &nbsp;
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

La manera correcta seria así (j.id en lugar de categoria.id):

```
{% for i in posts %}
        {% for j in i.categoria.all %}
            <a href="{% url 'categoria' j.id %}">{{j.nombre}}</a>
            | &nbsp;
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Esto ya debería de generarte la url con el parámetro categoria_id y ya se puede hacer el reverse con la url 'categoria'

Comment: Muchas gracias <3, tenia varios días intentando solucionar, según lo que entendí de tu corrección es que debo colocar el nombre de la variable de inicio del FOR . la propiedad

Comment: Asi es, cuando haces {% for j in i.categoria.all %} cada una de las categorias dentro de i.categoria.all se accede mediante {{ j }} y si quieres acceder a sus propiedades, es {{ j.campo }}